# Detect if `scrollIntoView` accepts an object paramenter

Tags: javascript, dom

The method [`element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) accepts one parameter. This parameter can be a boolean value or an object.

Currently, only Firefox supports the object syntax. I need to find a way to detect if the method allows an object to be passed.

The following is the code I'm trying to write:

```js
var acceptsObjects = // part that I'm missing

if (acceptsObjects) {
  element.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' })
} else {
  element.scrollIntoView(false)
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to automatically detect it without examining the code the function runs. I suppose it does something along the lines of `if (typeof param == "boolean") { /*do something*/ }` but, of course, that can take any shape or form, as well - it might check if the parameter is an object and using `!!` on it if it isn't, for example. Since the implementation can very well change, you can't really even check for those. _If_ you can get the code the function is running in the fist place, that is. So you're left with browser sniffing, on order to guess.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I was hoping there's some other thing you can check to figure out if the object parameter is supported

Comment: Well, the question is if other browsers are throwing errors if you pass in an object. If so, a simple try/catch block would let you set a Boolean for whether it works or not...

Comment: Unfortunately if I pass an object it gets casted as a `true` value

Answer (score 1):

My answer is quite late, but maybe it helps someone else:

```js
function supportsScrollIntoViewOptions() {
  var isSupported = false;

  try {
    var opts = {};
    Object.defineProperty(opts, 'block', {
      // define a getter on the opts object for the property 'block'
      // if an object as the argument is supported, this function will be called and 
      //   we can set `isSupported` to true
      get: function() {
        isSupported = true;
        return 'nearest';
      }
    });

    document.createElement('div').scrollIntoView(opts);
  } catch(e) {}

  return isSupported;
}
```

I have used `var` and old school method definitions for better backwards compatibility, as well as wrapped everything in a `try { … } catch(e) { … }`, which I’m not sure is necessary.

This was tested in Firefox 31.0, which returns `false` as well as Firefox 108.0.1 and Safari 15.5 which both return `true`. Even though Can I Use [claims this feature is not supported in Safari 15.5](https://caniuse.com/scrollintoview) it works.

Please let me know if there are any improvements to my code.

Comment: Kudos for answering seven years later I asked!